# This is everything about

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> This is everything about sinews.
>
> This is everything about armpits.

What does this simple structure really means? In my quotations the teller is talking about a book. Does he mean that the book is all about sinews and armpits? Or does he mean that everything you need to know about sinews and armpits is in this book. As far as I know both statements are not reasonable about that book. So I am wondering what he means.

Comment: The implication is actually even stronger: "Everything *there is to know* about sinews is in this book."  If that meaning is clearly not true (if the book is very small, for example), the person might be saying it humorously.

Comment: It's not possible to know without more context. It could mean different things.